# shaded theorem in minipage

Tags: beamer, minipage

I am typing up handouts using Beamer. In the handouts, I need a slide that shows a theorem and a figure next to it. All theorems in the handout are shaded using the package **shadetheorem**.

But this package doesn't seem to work well with minipage. I tried to abandon using this package and instead use the **mdframed** package, but the spacing before and after the text in the shaded boxes doesn't match those that use the shadetheorem package.

**How do I put a shaded theorem inside a minipage?** I'd prefer to stick to the shadetheorem package, since I have many other definitions and theorems relying on this package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,handout,mathserif]{beamer}
% PACKAGES
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{etex}% Gives more storage so that TeX will run properly
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsthm, array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}% justification of text
\usepackage{shadethm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, through, arrows, shadows, backgrounds, mindmap, patterns, plotmarks}
\RequirePackage{latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% HANDOUTS
%
%
\usepackage{pgffor}
\makeatletter
\def\strokeifnotempty{%
\expandafter\ifvoid\csname pgfpages@box@\the\pgf@cpn\endcsname
\let\@next=\relax
\else
\let\@next=\pgfstroke
\fi
\@next%
}
\makeatother

\mode<handout>
{
  \usepackage{pgf}
  \usepackage{pgfpages}
%
%
% 4 pages per sheet of paper
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{4 on 1 new}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperheight} 
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperwidth}
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
\pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions{
    logical pages=4, 
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight, 
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}\strokeifnotempty, 
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder, 
    resized width=.70\pgfphysicalwidth, 
    resized height=.52\pgfphysicalheight, 
    center = \pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth + 9mm}{.75\pgfphysicalheight - 9mm}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}\strokeifnotempty, 
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder, 
    resized width=.70\pgfphysicalwidth, 
    resized height=.52\pgfphysicalheight, 
    center = \pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth - 9mm}{.75\pgfphysicalheight - 9mm}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}\strokeifnotempty, 
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder, 
    resized width=.70\pgfphysicalwidth, 
    resized height=.52\pgfphysicalheight, 
    center = \pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth + 9mm}{.25\pgfphysicalheight + 9mm}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}\strokeifnotempty, 
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder, 
    resized width=.70\pgfphysicalwidth, 
    resized height=.52\pgfphysicalheight, 
    center = \pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth - 9mm}{.25\pgfphysicalheight + 9mm}
}
}

\IfFileExists{\jobname.aux}{\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1 new}[letterpaper, border shrink=12mm, landscape] \nofiles}{}
}
%
%
% Make a border around frames
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{ \tikz \draw[semithick] 
    (current page.north west) 
    rectangle 
    (current page.south east); }
%
%
%Centered page numbering for handouts
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{centered page number}
{%
    \hspace*{\fill}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
    {\color{black} \scriptsize \insertpagenumber }
    \hspace*{\fill}\vskip2pt%
}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[centered page number]
%
%
% END OF HANDOUT COMMANDS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\frenchspacing

\newshadetheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newshadetheorem{THM}{Theorem.}
\newshadetheorem{THM_mini}{Theorem in Minipage.}

\title[Title]{\bfseries Title}
\author[Author]{\large \bfseries Author}
\date[Date]{\large \bfseries Date}
\institute[University of X]

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title Page
\begin{frame}[t]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}
\begin{THM}
Here is a theorem. Here is an equation:
\[
    E = m c^2.
\]
Here is a theorem.
\end{THM}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}[c]{0.50\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[c]{1.0\textwidth - 1ex}
\begin{THM_mini}
Here is a theorem. Here is an equation:
\[
    E = m c^2.
\]
Here is a theorem.
\end{THM_mini}
\end{minipage}
\end{column}
\hfill%\vrule{}\hfill%
\begin{column}[c]{0.50\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[c]{1.0\textwidth - 1ex}
%\vspace{-4.75ex}
\noindent \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\hspace{4ex}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex', scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.95}]
% x-axis
\draw[semithick,->] (-0.5, 0) -- (3.5, 0)
    node[below] {$x\vphantom{b}$};
% y-axis
\draw[semithick, ->] (0, -0.5) -- (0, 3.5) 
    node[left] {$y$};   
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\vfill
\end{minipage}%
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't answer your question, possibly the answer is easy, but I will comment that I am the author of shadethm and I view that package as obsolete.  Personally I use thmtools, FWIW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the column environment. Just place two minipages next to each other inside the shadowed theorem environment.

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{THM_mini}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.58\textwidth}
Here is a theorem. Here is an equation:
\[
    E = m c^2.
\]
Here is a theorem.
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex', scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.95}]
% x-axis
\draw[semithick,->] (-0.5, 0) -- (3.5, 0)
    node[below] {$x\vphantom{b}$};
% y-axis
\draw[semithick, ->] (0, -0.5) -- (0, 3.5) 
    node[left] {$y$};   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\end{THM_mini}
\end{frame}
```

---

**EDIT:**

As I misunderstood the OP at first, here is the actual answer to what he wanted: To get a shaded theorem environment with half the text width the length `\shadedtextwidth` has to be set manually before defining a new theorem environment.

```
\setlength{\shadedtextwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
\newshadetheorem{THM_mini}{Theorem in Minipage.}
```

In this case the minipages are not necessary.

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}[c]{0.50\textwidth}
\begin{THM_mini}
Here is a theorem. Here is an equation:
\[
    E = m c^2.
\]
Here is a theorem.
\end{THM_mini}
\end{column}

\begin{column}[c]{0.50\textwidth}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex', scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.95}]
% x-axis
\draw[semithick,->] (-0.5, 0) -- (3.5, 0)
    node[below] {$x\vphantom{b}$};
% y-axis
\draw[semithick, ->] (0, -0.5) -- (0, 3.5) 
    node[left] {$y$};   
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

Thought about it a bit more. The first solution changes the width of all shaded theorems. That is probably not what you want. Maybe a simple

```
\let\shadedtextwidth\textwidth
```

is a better solution for you. This way the width of the shaded theorem is always the text width.

Comment: Ah, I didn't make this more explicit. What I'm hoping for is to have the shaded environment next to the figure (I don't want the figure inside the shaded environment). Sorry about that. Thanks for the response, though.

Comment: Ah, ok. So then you have to set the width of the shaded theorem manually. `\setlength{\shadedtextwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
\newshadetheorem{THM_mini}{Theorem in Minipage.}`. I will add a full example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for going back and thinking it over some more. I greatly appreciate it!